# linux command for finding files containing a specific word

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

basically what is says in the title, but i mean look for files CONTAINING a word, not in the filename but in the content. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with `grep` ;)

```
grep -r word DIR
```

`-r` is **recursive**

But there's also [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) that is working pretty closely as `grep`

Comment: +1. I use ack daily: it's recursive by default, and uses Perl regexes:.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgrep`.

```
rgrep pattern path
```

which is equivalent to

```
grep -r pattern path
```

If you only want to grep for whole words matching, you can add `-w` to the grep options.

Answer (score 0):

I use `grep` for that

```
grep -Ri "keyword" [dir]
```

**-R** recursive
**-i** ignore case